# How to resolve error: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA excluded from account secondary indexes; this RPC method unavailable for key'?

Tags: web3.js, token, owner

I am using `connection.getTokenLargestAccounts(new PublicKey(tokenAddress));` method to fetch the owners of a token. Calling this function like below, on an array of NFT address on mainnet-beta via Quicknode RPC endpoint.

```
const largestAcc = await connection.getTokenLargestAccounts(tokenAddress);
```

On doing above, I am running into this error:

```
"failed to get token largest accounts: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA excluded from account secondary indexes; this RPC method unavailable for key"
```

I am not calling getLargetstTokenAccount for `TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA`, but still getting the above error. Can anyone explain the root cause of this error, and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTokenLargestAccounts` requires an index on part of the token program, which is `TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA`.

This error is telling you that your node is not configured to serve any calls that require an index on the token program, ie. `getTokenLargestAccounts`, `getTokenAccountsByOwner`.

To fix this, you'll need to use another node or configure your existing node to also index token accounts by passing `--account-index spl-token-mint`. Note that this consumes much more RAM, so watch that the machine doesn't run out of memory!

You can find more info at https://docs.solana.com/running-validator/validator-start#account-indexing